# Is there anyway to do feature selection in a dataset which has only cases

Tags: feature-selection

I have dataset which has only cases in it and no controls. Is it possible to do feature selection in such datasets. Ultimately, i want to make a prediction model that predicts the case.

Comment: What is a case and what is a control in your definition? If you reformulate your question, I can give you an answer.

Comment: The data is of  patients with  Gastrointestinal bleeding, contains medication, comorbidities, some other basic information..  The doesn't have controls/healthy patients (i.e. patients without Gastrointestinal bleeding).  As a first step I want to feature selection. Ultimately i am trying to find out whether any of the variables are associated with Gastrointestinal bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any feature selection method that does not take the target variable into account. A simple example is removing highly correlated features.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, what you are looking for is an unsupervised feature selection method.

There are at least two ways to view feature selection methods [[1]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3136625):

1. **Supervision perspective**

   - *Supervised* feature selection that, with supervision information, is assessed via its correlation with the class labels (for classification tasks) or the regression target (for regression ones).
   - *Unsupervised* feature selection is generally designed for clustering problems, which has no label information to evaluate the process and therefore seeks for alternative criteria to define feature relevance.
   - *Semi-supervised* feature selection is the process that combines supervised and unsupervised approaches, where the available data are partially labeled, but not all of them.
2. **Selection strategy perspective**

   - *Wrapper* methods rely on the predictive performance of a learning algorithm to evaluate the quality of selected features.
   - *Filter* methods rely on (statistical) characteristics of data to assess feature importance and are typically more computationally efficient than wrapper ones.
   - *Embedded* methods are a trade-off between filter and wrapper methods that embed the feature selection into model learning.

There is also a **data perspective** [[1]](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3136625).

I leave you some references for a more in-depth investigation:

- [A survey on feature selection methods](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045790613003066)
- [A survey on semi-supervised feature selection methods](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320316303545)
- [A review of unsupervised feature selection methods](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10462-019-09682-y)